# scipy.signal.freqz function

Tags: python, matplotlib, frequency-analysis

The scipy library of matplotlib in Python 3 contains a function `scipy.signal.freqz` which computes the frequency response of a digital filter.

I am trying to write my own version of this function, to relay the same output as this embedded function. I plan to use the inputs:

```
freqz(b, a = 1, worN=None, whole=None): 
    [b=numerator of linear filter; 
     a=denominator of linear filter; 
     worN=at none, compute at 512 frequencies equally spaced around the unit circle; 
     whole=at none, frequency computed around upper half of unit circle, from 0 to pi]
```

This function should output two outputs:

```
w and h 
[w=ndarray, the normalized frequencies at which h was computed, in radians/sample; 
 h=ndarray, the frequency response]
```

current code:

```
def freqz(b, a=1, worN=None, whole=False):

#Initialize a
a = atleast_1d(a)

#Initialize b
b = atleast_1d(b)

#Check condition
if worN is None:

    #Initialize worN
    worN = 512

#Initialize
h = None

#Try block
try:

    #Update
    worN = operator.index(worN)

#Exception
except TypeError:

    #Update
    w = atleast_1d(worN)

#Otherwise
else:

    #Check condition
    if worN < 0:

        #Throw an exception
        raise ValueError('worN should be non negative, we got %s' % (worN,))

    #Update
    finalpoint = 2 * pi if whole else pi

    #Update
    w = np.linspace(0, finalpoint, worN, endpoint=False)

    #Check condition       
    if (a.size == 1 and worN >= b.shape[0] and fftpack.next_fast_len(worN) == worN and (b.ndim == 1 or (b.shape[-1] == 1))):

        #Update
        nfft = worN if whole else worN * 2

        #Check condition
        if np.isrealobj(b) and np.isrealobj(a):

            #Update
            fftfunc = np.fft.rfft

        #Otherwise
        else:

            #Update
            fftfunc = fftpack.fft

        #Update
        h = fftfunc(b, n=nfft, axis=0)[:worN]

        #Update
        h /= a

        #Check condition
        if fftfunc is np.fft.rfft and whole:

            #Update
            stop = -1 if nfft % 2 == 1 else -2

            #Update
            hVal_flip = slice(stop, 0, -1)

            #Update
            h = np.concatenate((h, h[hVal_flip].conj()))

        #Check condition
        if b.ndim > 1:

            #Update
            h = h[..., 0]

            #Update
            h = np.rollaxis(h, 0, h.ndim)
#Delete
del worN

#Check condition
if h is None:

    #Update
    zmVal = exp(-1j * w)

    #Update
    h = (npp_polyval(zmVal, b, tensor=False)/npp_polyval(zmVal, a, tensor=False))

#Check condition       
return w, h
```

Comment: please explain what you've tried... since the code exists, I'd suggest you just go read it to understand how it works.

Comment: i added the code i currently have above, i am getting an error with the "operator.index(worN)" code